# Evaluate $\int \frac{\left(x^2+x+3\right)\left(x^3+7\right)}{x+1}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, polynomials

> Evaluate:
> $$\int \frac{\left(x^2+x+3\right)\left(x^3+7\right)}{x+1}dx$$

The only thing I can think of doing here is long division to simplify the integral down and see if I can work with some easier sections. Here's my attempt:

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\left(x^2+x+3\right)\left(x^3+7\right)}{x+1}dx &= \int \left(\:x^4+3x^2+4x+3+\frac{18}{x+1} \right )dx \\
&= \int \:x^4dx+\int \:3x^2dx+\int \:4xdx+\int \:3dx+\int \frac{18}{x+1}dx \\
&= \frac{x^5}{5}+x^3+2x^2+3x+18\ln \left|x+1\right|+ c, c \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}

The only issue I had is that the polynomial long division took quite some time. Is there another way to do this that is less time consuming? The reason I ask this is that, this kind of question can come in an exam where time is of the essence so anything that I can do to speed up the process will benefit me greatly.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B3%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28x%5E3%2B7%5Cright%29%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D) help?

Comment: Writing $x^2 + x + 3 = x(x+1) + 3$ may help slightly.

Comment: You can expand the numerator and use Horner's method for division. It's a bit faster.

Comment: @player3236 Especially if we also write $x^3+7$ as $x^3+1+6$, so the integrand is $(x(x+1)+3)(x^2-x+1+6/(x+1))$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do the substitution $x+1=t\iff x=t-1$ you only need do a (long) multiplication:

$$\int \frac{\left(x^2+x+3\right)\left(x^3+7\right)}{x+1}dx=
\int \frac{\left((t-1)^2+t+2\right)\left((t-1)^3+7\right)}{t}dt=
$$
$$=\int \frac{\left(t^2-t+3\right)\left(t^3-3t^2+3t+6\right)}{t}dt=\int \frac{t^5-4 t^4+9 t^3-6 t^2+3 t+18}{t}dt=$$
$$=\int\left( t^4-4 t^3+9 t^2-6 t+3 +\frac{18}{t}\right)dt
$$
And now it's simple.

Comment: This is my favorite approach to partial fractions with a linear denominator.

Comment: Wow this is so much less time consuming than my approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

*Horner's method for division*:

$$(x^2+x+3)(x^3+7)=x^5+x^4+3x^3+7x^2+7x+21$$

\begin{array}{*{7}{r}}
& 1 & 1  & 3 & 7 & 7 & 21 \\ 
+ & \downarrow & -1 & 0 & -3 & -4 & -3 \\
\hline
\times -1 & \color{red}1 &  \color{red}0 &  \color{red}3 &  \color{red}4 &  \color{red}3 & \color{cyan}{18}
\end{array}
so the quotient is $\;x^4+3x^2+4x+3$ and the remainder is $\;18$.

Comment: +1 Synthetic division blew my mind when I was first taught it, and still continues to do so. A great tip not enough students know about.

Comment: Isn't it taught in high-school?

Comment: During my time (about 1989) in Singapore, I learned it in Secondary school (when I was 14 going on 15). It wasn't a method featured in the (UK-sourced) textbooks of the time (which only covered the longhand method of polynomial division) but the teacher taught this as a useful shortcut. I'm not sure if it was universally taught in all schools at that level (the school I attended has generally been regarded as the best in the country) and I don't know the situation now.

Comment: +1 for using this technique. I don't think it's a part of typical high school curriculum, but it is not something difficult and very useful.

Comment: @Bernard Wow thanks for the answer! I know that you can use Horner's Method to convert between binary and decimal numbers but this is the first time I have seen it used to divide polynomials. Nice answer.

Comment: @SkiMask: It is a by-product of Horner's method  for evaluating a polynomial at a point, e.g. if $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, instead of calculating the successive powers of $\alpha$, multiplying by the coefficients and adding all the stuff, it is much faster to play with parentheses, namely $p(\alpha)=\bigl((a \alpha+b)\alpha+c\bigr)\alpha+d$.

Answer (score 3):

As substitution by parts goes nowhere It simply do what you did but skip the step of multiplying out the polynomial $ \frac{\left(x^2+x+3\right)\left(x^3+7\right)}{x+1}=\frac {(x(x+1) + 3)(x^3+7)}{x+1}= x(x^3 +7) + \frac 3{x+1}(x^3 + 7)=$

$x(x^3 +7) +\frac 3{x+1}(x^2(x+1) -x(x+1) + x+1 + 6)=x(x^3 +7) + 3(x^2-x+1) + \frac {18}{x+1} $

Saves one or two tablets of ibuprofen.

Comment: Haha saving ibuprofen. +1 good advice one may need the tablet in future for difficult problems.